# input type text issue,

Tags: jquery, html

I am writing a jquery function to check if user input contains letters instead of numbers. Im just trying to get the basic functionality working and I am using an alert box to test this. The test should be displaying the alert regardless of what is entered. It works when numbers are entered, but any other character entered does not fire the alert,. Any ideas what is going on here?

The form is broken into fieldsets contained in divs, which pop-up as overlays. The function is called whenever the user tries to close a pop-up window,. Not that this should cause a problem?

Here is the test function:

```
function validateItem(item){
var fvalue = $(item).val();
alert(fvalue);
return false;  }
```

Here is a sample table item

```
<tr>
<td class="td_thumbs">
    <div>
        <a class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="vinyl-banners" href="img/products/vinyl-corporateblue.jpg"> <img src="img/products/thumbs/vinyl-corporateblue-thumb.png" alt="vinyl c-blue"/></a>
        <label>Corporate Blue</label>
    </div>
</td>
<td>6</td>
<td>
    <input id="vinyl-blue" type="text" max="6" min="0" value="0"/>
</td>
</tr>
```

The calling function,

```
//iterate through each table
    $('table').each(function() {

        $thisTable = $(this);

        //iterate through each input
        $(this).find('input').each(function() {
            var $this = $(this), i_value = $this.attr('value'),
                itemLabel = $this.closest('tr').find('label').html();
            //if any items have a positive value
            if (i_value > 0) {
                //we want to grab the heading for these items
                setHeading = true;

                //validate item
                if(validateItem($this)){//if quantities are valid
                  //build list of items of this type
                 $this.css({
                      'border':'1px solid #ddd',
                      'background-color' : '#efefef'
                      });
                      items += '<li>' + i_value + 'x ' + itemLabel + '</li>';
                }
                else{//invalid quantity
                  $this.css({
                      'border':'1px dashed #F00',
                      'background-color' : '#f7d2d4'
                      });

                      errorFlag = true;
                      //exit item and table loops    
                      return false;                  
                }//end validate                

            }//end value check
        });//end input iteration
```

Comment: Can you show how your validateItem is actually getting called and what parameters you are passing to it?

Comment: I have updated my Q for you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue! The function was called within the following..

```
if (i_value > 0) {
```

which meant it was only called when a number was input. I placed the call outside of this if statement and it works as expected, so the solution was to change

```
if(i_value > 0)
```

to

```
if(i_value != 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is function where you can get the content of an input box whether it is a number or alphabet you can [Check Here](http://jsfiddle.net/52QfW/2/)

however If you don't want user to enter any number you can use onkeypress event

as following [Check here](http://jsfiddle.net/52QfW/5/)

```
onkeypress
```

Comment: Thanks ameya_rote, I will implement these and get back to you.

Comment: Neither of the posted solutions worked for me when adapted to my program. The same issue occurs that the alert is not fired. I will have to try a few other things and figure out what is going on..

Comment: You are not integrating it prperly then...cause given fiddle code works exactly as u described..